# Can´t export gltf with face texture image

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, image

hello i am beginner and im trying to do a lowpoly mode of my character. the problem is. when im export an animation with gltf the face doesn't show
[image]

and i dont know why. maybe it's because i have a group of nodes that manage the face expresion
[image]

[image]

i will be thankfully for  your help